# What is the source of 64 megabytes blocks in python threading run?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I found out that on linux 64 bits systems, every time you create a python thread, a 64 megabytes anonymous block is made available.

```
00007f4da6371000   8192K rw---    [ anon ]
00007f4da6b72000   8192K rw---    [ anon ]
00007f4d64021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d6c021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d70021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d74021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d78021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d7c021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d80021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d84021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d88021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d90021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d94021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d98021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4d9c021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
00007f4da0021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
 total          1076628K
```

Obtained through this trivial case

```
>>> import threading
>>> class A(threading.Thread):
...     def run(self):
...             while True:
...                     pass
... 
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
>>> A().start()
```

My first suspects were thread stack and thread local storage, but I can't find any point where 65 megabytes is the needed amount. In fact, all checks (e.g. threading.stack_size, the thread_pthread.c content, ulimit -a) point at amounts much smaller than that. Who is deciding this amount and creating this VM block?

Answer (score 2):

64MB of address space is reserved for the stack. Address space in a 64-bit process is effectively free, so there's no reason to reserve less space. (This is a great improvement from 32-bit systems where you had to make painful tradeoffs.)

Don't be mislead into thinking this is physical memory. This is a virtual mapping.

Comment: I know it's not physical, yet I can't find this value anywhere. According to ulimit, the stack size should be 8192k, not 64 megabytes, and I assume that thread stack size is the same, otherwise you could override the ulimit by doing all the work in a separate thread.

Comment: @StefanoBorini You *can* override the ulimit by doing all the work in a separate thread. (It is essentially impossible to limit the stack size other than by limiting virtual mappings entirely. There's no good way to tell how big a stack could grow to other than the size of the segment.)

Comment: ok, that's interesting... and weird if you ask me. Yet the problem remains. Who decides this 64 megabytes value? kernel, pthreads, or python?

Comment: What's the problem? It's python that decides. You can [set the stack size in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html), but you should not do so. Why make a painful tradeoff you don't need to make?

Comment: As from my question, stack_size does not produce that value. It returns a zero, which means default, which then maps to a macro value for the default, which eventually leads to `#define THREAD_STACK_MIN        0x8000  /* 32kB */`. in thread_pthread.h Still no 64 megabytes.

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand who decides this 64 megabytes, and I am trying to understand that.

Comment: Even PTHREAD_STACK_MIN is 16k `x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h:#define PTHREAD_STACK_MIN 16384`

Comment: @StefanoBorini It's a complex combination of the architecture, the process context, the threading library, and python. Each of them (except the architecture) have conditions under which they can raise or lower the value.